# Accessing mvc controller from view using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to send data to a controller so I can get data back but it doesn't seem to even get to the controller.  here's my ajax:

```
$('#clicker').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetControllerVideo", "Login")',
        success: function (ItemId) {
            alert(ItemId)
        }
    });
});
```

Controller actions(Updated):

```
        private string getVideo(Guid? FileId, string culture)
    {
        if (null == FileId || !FileId.HasValue)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string videoCulture = (culture.ToLower() == "en-us" ? "" : "." + culture);

        string model = null;
        using (InRollPlus.API.Repositories.FileRepository fir = new FileRepository())
        {
            //model = fir.Get(FileId.Value);
            //model.Location = String.Format(@"{0}/{1}/{2}/video{3}{4}", InRollPlus.Shared.ConstantVals.ConstantItem.AWS_ENVIRONMENT, Shared.Utils.AWSHelpers.AS3.S3Folder.video, benefitTypeId, videoCulture, model.FileNameExtension);
        }
        return (model);
    }

    private IEnumerable<dynamic> GetVideoIdByController(string controllerName, string videoCulture)
    {
        var VideoService = new AppServices.Video.GetVideoById();
        IEnumerable<dynamic> videoFileId = VideoService.Execute(controllerName);
        return (videoFileId);
    }

    public string GetControllerVideo(Guid id, string videoCulture)
    {
        var controllerName = this.GetType().ToString();
        dynamic LookupData = GetVideoIdByController(controllerName, videoCulture);
        Guid? FileItemId = LookupData.ItemId;
        return (getVideo(FileItemId, videoCulture));
    }
```

When I put a break point on GetControllerVideo and do a debug, nothing happens.  It's as though it never even hits the controller.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) Show us the controller action. 2) Watch the browser's network monitor and debug console. Do you see any errors?

Comment: Controller action:  `public string GetControllerVideo(Guid id, string videoCulture)
        {
            var controllerName = this.GetType().ToString();
            dynamic LookupData = GetVideoIdByController(controllerName, videoCulture);
            Guid? FileItemId = LookupData.ItemId;
            return (getVideo(FileItemId, videoCulture));
        }`

Comment: Also, do not see any errors in console or when I debug.

Comment: Your action needs two parameters. They also should be named the same as the data you're passing via Ajax.

Comment: I updated my question as I'm actually not trying to send data to the controller, but getting data FROM the controller.

Comment: If you check the network tab from Chrome(idk how it works in Firebug) you see a `500 Internal Server Error` right? That's because your action needs 2 parameters and you pass none

Comment: Watch the browser's network monitor. If you don't know how to use this valuable debugging tool see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255004(v=vs.85).aspx. Debugging with Chrome or FF is very similar. What does the _Request Header_ and _Response Header_ look like?

Comment: When I check the monitor, I get an a request sent and a status of 200 which is an ok status, but why doesn't hit the debug point I set?

Comment: GET requests are often cached and you could see the result of a previously cached request. Clear the browser's cache to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Try adding 'cache: false' to your Ajax call which should solve caching issues which @Jasen is likely correct about.

Comment: I add 'cache: false' and I still get a 200 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `itemId` to `id` and pass `videoCulture` too, since your action needs 2 parameters called `id` and `videoCulture`

```
$('#clicker').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetControllerVideo", "Login")',
        data: { Id: "FileItemId", videoCulture: "SomethingHere" },
        success: function (ItemId) {
            alert(ItemId)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: See my updated question.  I'm not posting to the controller but getting from the controller

Comment: Edited my answer too.

Comment: Updated my code, but still doesn't hit the breakpoint I set in 'GetControllerVideo".  What gives?

Comment: @JeffMcbride: The parameters will also need to match the expected type. Did you provide a string version of a valid GUID for the id parameter?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I am getting the Guid in the controller.  Now I see that I don't need  (Guid id, string videoCulture).  Just ().  But why am I not hitting the breakpoint set within the controller at all.  I should at least hit that and get some sort of error, right?

Comment: @JeffMcbride: You will not see the error server side. You need to use a tool like Fiddler2 to view the HTTP requests and see what the server is responding with (404, 500 and error message etc)

Comment: Are you sure the controller is not in a different Area from where you call the ajax? If so you need to change the url to `@Url.Action("GetControllerVideo", "Login", new { area = "AREANAME"})`

Comment: View is under "views\login\index.cshtml" and controller is under "Controllers\LoginController.cs".  So it should be the same area which is why I didn't include that.  They are both on the root.

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you build your application includin Debug Trace?

Comment: Yes, it was built that way.

Comment: It's like it's hitting the controller but not returning the data because `alert(ItemId)` just returns a bunch of html.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my application does not allow for unathenticated requests to a controller, so when I hit that controller it just sends a return redirect and gives me a 200 ok status.  I'm going to have to do things differently.